# Realm version Migration renaming property not existed

Tags: ios, swift, migration, realm, version

Hi I have Realm migration but have meet error

below is my situation error scenario

first

I have a simple `User` Model of schemeVersion 0 (default)

```
class User: Object {
    dynamic var username = ""
    dynamic var date = NSDate()
}
```

add date2 in version 1

```
class User: Object {
    dynamic var username = ""
    dynamic var date = NSDate()
    dynamic var date2 = NSDate()
}
```

and migrate

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 1,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
            if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: RealmUser.className(), { (oldObject, newObject) in
                    newObject!["date2"] = oldObject!["date"] as! NSDate
                })
            }
}
```

and add date3 in version 3 and rename date3 to date 4 in version 4

```
class User: Object {
    dynamic var username = ""
    dynamic var date = NSDate()
    dynamic var date2 = NSDate()
    dynamic var date4 = NSDate()
}
```

and migrate

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 4,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
            if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: RealmUser.className(), { (oldObject, newObject) in
                    newObject!["date2"] = oldObject!["date"] as! NSDate
                })
            }

            if oldSchemaVersion < 2 {
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: RealmUser.className(), { (oldObject, newObject) in
                    newObject!["date3"] = oldObject!["date2"] as! NSDate
                })
            }

            if oldSchemaVersion < 3 {
                migration.renameProperty(onType: User.className(), from: "date3", to: "date4")
            }
}
```

When I have migrated sequencely 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 work fine

but when migrate from 0 version to 4 version cause `fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error`

`"Cannot rename property 'User.date3' because it does not exist."`

in this case how can i migrate 0 ~ 3 version to 4 without above not exist exeption ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If schemaVersion 3 is only one that has "date3", version 3 has to be handled separately (I don't know what happen in schemaVersion 2). And you can't insert oldObject["date2"] to newObject["date3"], because newObject does not have date3 as error. The purpose of migration is matching the oldscheme with the present scheme. Try it in your project, it worked with me!

```
 Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
       schemaVersion: 4, 
       migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
       migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: User.className(), { (oldObject, newObject) in
           if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
               newObject?["date2"] = oldObject!["date"] as! NSDate
           }
           // use newObject["date2"] instead of oldObject["date2"] for schemaVerion 0
           if oldSchemaVersion < 2 {
               newObject?["date4"] = newObject?["date2"] as! NSDate
           }
      })
      // separate version 3 for "date3"
      if oldSchemaVersion == 3 {
          migration.renameProperty(onType: User.className(), from: "date3", to: "date4")
      }
})
```

And I recommend you use func enumerateObjects once. You don't need to fetch all objects every time. I hope it will work!

Comment: it save my times Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a migration for each property which will exist in the final version of your schema but wasn't in the original because Realm needs to add this property to everything you already have in the database (that's what the migration does - it fills in the holes).  Why do you want to remove the code you have which works? You get an exception for date3 because it doesn't exist in schema 0, and you say you want to go directly from 0 to 4... You can either start over with complete definitions for all properties and reload all your data from scratch without a migration, or leave your working code as it is. there's nothing wrong with it. Ask me about anything that I haven't explained sufficiently.

Comment: I thought of another option for you: if you can start with a populated DB, use a copy of your current database (schema 4) as your "version 0" and remove all migration code. and make sure you have code which populates date3, etc. properly on an insert (add).